# Get velocity or deviation of hand, during manipulation on Hololens2 with MRTK2.5

Tags: position, hololens, mrtk

**What I'm trying to do:**
I am using MRTK2.5.1 / Hololens2 and the OnlineMaps asset in Unity. I want to use my hand (by either touching map, or pointer from distance) to scroll the map. i.e. tap/grip the map, then drag hand around x/z plane.

**What I've done previously:**
With holotoolkit/hololens1, this was easily done with a listener for manipulation events.
The OnManipulationChanged event provided me with a CumulativeDelta value of how the hand position had changed since the start of the manipulation.

**What I've tried in MRTK2.5:**
I started off with ManipulationHandler, which gives me the pointer in eventdata. The pointer->controller has a velocity value, but that's always 0,0,0. I couldn't see anything else obvious relating to velocity or delta position of the thing (hand) triggering the manipulation.

The PointerHandler script has an OnPointerDragged event, but again has no property that looks like a velocity or delta position of hand.

Do i need to be using Gestures?

Not looking for code, just a brief explanation of the correct approach to get the hand velocity or deviation of hand, once the hand has tapped/clicked on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [ManipulationHandler](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ManipulationHandler.html) component is deprecated and [ObjectManipulator](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ObjectManipulator.html) component is a replacement  for manipulation behavior. So it is recommended you start with the Object Manipulator component to makes your map movable.

For your question about how to scroll the map around x/z plane, [Constraint](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ConstraintManager.html) is aimed at limiting manipulation in some way. Once constraint enabled on your ObjectManipulator component, transform changes will be processed by constraints registered to the selected constraint manager. In your case, MoveAxisConstraint can meet your need, you can add MoveAxisConstraint to game object from Constraint Manager component and set the `Constraint On Movement` property of Move Axis Constraint component to `Y Axis`. For more information about MoveAxisConstraint please refer to: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ConstraintManager.html#moveaxisconstraint

Comment: I don't want the map to be movable, Manipulation/ObjectManipulator have already been used to constrain movement of the map object. I need the hand movement information, so i can use that to dictate the map scroll speed and direction.

Comment: I am not familiar with OnlineMaps, but if what you want to obtain is the raw data of your hand movement, the sample Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/Input/Scenes/InputData/InputDataExample provided by MRTK show how to do it.